# Generate video from images with ken burns effect using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, zooming

I am trying to generate video from images.

The following code generates the video,  1 frames per 3 seconds.

```
     exec("ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/3 -loop_input -shortest -y  -i tmp/image%3d.jpg -i tmp/ag1.mp3 -target ntsc-dvd -s 1280x720 tmp/video.mwv");
```

I want to apply ken burns effect to it,  I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution.

Can anybody help me out ? If can provide any code snippet, will be really appreciated.

Comment: You can use Imagemagick's -distort SRT to do scale, rotation and translation in some script loop to generate the effect. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#srt

Comment: I wrote this project that might be helpful to you or others that land here: [gibatronic/fotofx](https://github.com/gibatronic/fotofx/releases/tag/v1.1.0)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this can be done with ffmpeg alone.  I have done this in the past with a tool called [diascope](http://diascope.sourceforge.net).  I never hear much about it, but it produces some of the best picture slideshows I have seen since you can use effects like Ken Burns.  It does use ffmpeg in its final step to actually encode the video.

Take a look at the examples, it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: To let diascope run in ubuntu 12, I had to install gawk instead of the default mawk, change /usr/local/bin/diascope to use gawk, and change its invocation of its generated script "kenburns_slideshow.sh" (look for 'nice') to explicitly call /bin/bash (chmod u+x just before that had no effect, no idea why).

Comment: Also, diascope fails when run in an smb-mounted win7 directory (unless you specify "base basename /tmp".  That's because it calls imagemagick's `convert` to create an image as a pair of files foo.mpc and foo.cache ("mpc format").  That renders as pure black.  But on local linux disk, both `convert` and diascope work.

Comment: One more fix: remove diascope's "-aspect %s %s" args passed to ffmpeg, to create a proper 16x9 video instead of a square one.

Answer (score 2):

FFMPEG has https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan

Currently it does have some issues with shaky video motion.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a combination of Imagemagick and ffmpeg.   Use image magic to make a series of cropped images and ffmpeg to turn the series of images into a movie.
Cropping the images with ImageMagick should be done along one or more vectors to create the "frames" that create the motion.   All images will have to have the same outer dimensions of course (easy to do with ImageMagick), but you can create all kinds of frame by frame motion using the cropping and zooming tools in ImageMagick.

Comment: This combination is exactly what diascope does (Jason B's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ken-Burns can be applied  with [Mencoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder). See [Encoding with MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/encoding-guide.html). The [PhotoFilmstrip](http://www.photofilmstrip.org/) program is like a  GUI for Mencoder. It is Python-based and hence available for Windows (even as portable version) and Linux. For Linux there's also [image2mpeg](http://www.gromeck.de/?image2mpeg), but I haven't tried it yet.

Under Windows the free Microsoft MovieMaker can apply Ken-Burns too. Although it creates only WMV files MovieMakers GUI IMHO is way better than PhotoFilmStrips'. The silver bullet, however, is to apply MEncoder in a batch or shell script. As a start search for "mencoder syntax".

Answer (score 0):

Try this script with ImageMagick (version 6.x)

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( resizepercent=100; resizepercent<=200; resizepercent+=10 ))
do
    convert bird.jpg -resize $resizepercent% -gravity Center -crop 1800x1900+0+0 bird$resizepercent.png
done
```

You have to substitute "1800x1900" by your targeted output dimensions and maybe the "+0+0" by some other offset you want to zoom to.

Maybe some reader has an idea whether this script could be improved in performance!? The way I implemented it Imagemagick has to read the input file "bird.jpg" every single loop. Maybe there is an approach to tell Imagemagick to read the input file only once and scale it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can!**

Just use this:

```bash
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i photo.jpg -y -filter_complex "[0]scale=1200:-2,setsar=1:1[out];[out]crop=1200:670[out];[out]scale=8000:-1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.001':x=iw/2-(iw/zoom/2):y=0:d=250:s=1200x670:fps=25[out]" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -map [out] -map 0:a? -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -t 10 video.mp4
```

Extracted from: https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-do-a-ken-burns-style-effect-with-ffmpeg/