# How can I apply zoom in/out filter on specific frame in video using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, zooming

I want to apply zoom filter on specific frame on video using ffmpeg.

for example, I want to make a slideshow of 5 images and each image will take 4-5 seconds for slide. I want zoom in/out effect on each image. So, i want to apply this effect at that time when particular image stay for 4-5 seconds. Please see this video link. I want same result like this using ffmpeg: https://youtu.be/nNTiyRDhlRY please refer first two slides of this link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zooming animation in FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240841/zooming-animation-in-ffmpeg)

Comment: that's not my answer. please read carefully my question. i want to zoom in 1 perticular frame in my video. @AksenP

Comment: have a look at https://el-tramo.be/blog/ken-burns-ffmpeg/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084473/generate-video-from-images-with-ken-burns-effect-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate video from images with ken burns effect using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084473/generate-video-from-images-with-ken-burns-effect-using-ffmpeg)